# Add qualified class to Java comment instead of importing the class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, comments

Android Studio (Intellij)offers an option to instead of importing a class when it's just used in a comment (as the following) :

```
package com.mypackage;
import android.content.Intent;
/**
 * List all request codes used in our app.
 *  Ex: the request code used to call
 *  {@link android.app.Activity#startActivityForResult(Intent, int)}
 */
public final class RequestCodes {

    public static final int UNDEFINED = 110;

    public static final int ACTIVITY_REQUEST_OPEN_ACCOUNT = 21;
    public static final int AUTOCOMPLETE = 12;
    public static final int BARCODE = 13;
    public static final int CAPTURE_CAMERA_REQUEST = 14;
    public static final int DISPLAY_TEXT = 5;
    public static final int GET_PICTURE_FROM_CAMERA = 16;
    public static final int GET_PICTURE_FROM_GALLERY = 17;
    public static final int GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 18;
    public static final int IMAGE_SELECTION = 19;
    public static final int MAP_REQUEST = 110;
    public static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 111;
    public static final int RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 121;
}
```

use the qualified class name in the comment (as follows):

```
package com.mypackage;

/**
 * List all request codes used in our app.
 *  Ex: the request code used to call
 *  {@link android.app.Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)}
 */
public final class RequestCodes {
    .... same as previous
}
```

Exists an option use `android.content.Intent` at the comment instead of `import` the **class** just for the comment ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution but I have to use "Always" because "If not already imported" is not working.

[image: Android Studio Preferences]